# how to install bootstrap to twentyfourteen theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, theme-twenty-fourteen

Im new with using wordpress and im wondering if it is possible to install bootstrap to my twentyfourteen theme? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way to include **bootstrap** in your theme is to enqueue bootstrap CSS and JS in your functions.php file.

This is how you can enqueue bootstrap CSS and JS from CDN hosted version.

```
function my_scripts_enqueue() {
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, NULL, 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_enqueue' );
```

If you do not want to use CDN hosted version then download and put the bootstrap stuff in your theme, and include it like this.

```
function my_scripts_enqueue() {
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, NULL, 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_enqueue' );
```

Comment: thank you Robert. Do i still need to include the bootstrap files inside my wordpress folder?

Comment: If you are using CDN hosted version (first code block) then you do not need to add anything else in your theme folder. I also would recommend you to use CDN version.