# Installing Bootstrap on Twentyeleven Theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone tell me how to enable Bootstrap on a site using the twentyeleven theme? I followed the instructions for activating Bootstrap with the [twentyfourteen theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/163209/how-to-install-bootstrap-to-twentyfourteen-theme) without success.

This is the code I uploaded in the functions.php in my twentyeleven-child folder:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/style.css' );
}

function my_scripts_enqueue() {
  wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js',  '://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js',  array('jquery'), NULL, true );
  wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css',  '://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css', false,   NULL, 'all' );

 wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_enqueue' );
?>
```

Do I have to manually activate it somehow after I upload the file?

**EDIT:**

I just checked my source code and discovered that I have "enabled" Bootstrap...

http://mysite://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

The obvious problem is that the style sheet links point to my site, rather than maxcdn. Does anyone know how I can fix that?

I guess the obvious answer is to just find the files that hold the style sheet and JS links and insert the Bootstrap links manually?

Answer (score 1):

The way of using script and style enqueuing is correct, I think the error here lies in the column before the double "//" prefix of maxcdn URL. Try to remove the column in both urls.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it didn't fix the problem; it changed the URL's a bit, but the link to the Bootstrap files still include my domain name.

Comment: Didn't find any reference in wordpress codex, but maybe your browser/your configuration cannot handle the protocol-less urls (that is: `//something.com` instead of `http[s]://something.com`). I'd try to change the maxcdn url to standard `https://` urls)

Answer (score 1):

write the following in your code

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() .   '/style.css' );
}

function my_scripts_enqueue() {
wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js',  'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js',  array('jquery'), NULL, true );
wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css',  'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css', false,   NULL, 'all' );

wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_enqueue' );
?>
```

it will download your file